# What close reason for nonsense questions?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Imagine someone asks "what colour socks are best for reducing blood pressure?" We can't answer that, because the colour of your socks has **no effect** on your blood pressure. I want to close such questions (detox baths, foods to enlarge the penis, etc) but I don't know what close reason to use. They aren't too broad, nor opinion based. They generally aren't asking for personal medical advice or diagnosis. They just have this nutty idea and want someone to elaborate on it.

I don't know if we have a spare custom reason, but if we do, perhaps we could craft one to cover these?

I quite like the hand-typed reason on this homeopathy question: [Homeopathic remedy for low testosterone?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/homeopathic-remedy-for-low-testosterone) perhaps we could use that as a starting point:

> there are not enough people familiar with evidence of homeopathy to adequately judge an answer to this question. See previous homeopathy questions that have been downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be the option *blatantly off-topic*, which would be suitable in your examples.

I wouldn't waste my breath on such questions and type a long and extensive comment explaining what exactly is wrong - the question in question is not salvageable and I rather spent my time helping other new users with borderline odd-topic questions.

Maybe we can get a blatantly-off-topic reason, otherwise we'll have to type that by hand.

Comment: "Unclear" can often work.  Alt-med terms (eg. "toxins") are frequently sufficiently ill-defined that it's hard to tell what, if anything, the user is really asking.